# Render html response from string in python tornado library

Tags: python, html, tornado

I need to render response from html string in tornado like this:

`self.method_to_render_html_from_string('<h1>Hello</h1>')`

How can I do it? Tornado version is 6.1.
Here how it's displayed as for now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnjFL.jpg)

Answers, not related to tornado, are appreciated too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a response, use `self.write`:

```py
def get(self):
    self.write('<h1>Hello</h1>')
```

---

If you want to generate html from template string, then use [`tornado.template.Template`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html#module-tornado.template):

```py
from tornado.template import Template

def get(string):
    t = Template('<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>')
    self.write(t.generate(name='John'))
```

---

**Update:**

If the response is being sent as plain text, you can try setting the `Content-Type: text/html` header to send the response as HTML:

```py
def get(self):
    self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    self.write('<h1>Hello</h1>)
```

Comment: It displays in browsers with ```<h1>``` tags if using ```self.write('<h1>Hello</h1>')```. What can be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RomanIvanets It seems like the response is being sent as `text/plain` but it's strange because Tornado by default sends response as `text/html`. However, you try setting the `Content-Type: text/html` header. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's working :)

Comment: Can't cast a vote because the lack of reputation.

Comment: @RomanIvanets That's alright. If this answer solved your problem, you can mark is "accepted" by clicking on the check icon on the left.